# Converting Filetime to use in timer

Tags: c, winapi

I want to use a filetime as the due time in a waitable timer. I've managed to get the filetime of the current time and subtract that from the time i want the timer to go off, which seems to work just fine. The problem is that the timer needs the filetime in negative and i have no idea how to convert the filetime to negative.

I've tried multiplying the result with -1 but that gives me something totally different. I get the result in a ULONGLONG as filetime and if there's 30 seconds until the timer should fire and i multiply that with -1 it turns into like 50000 years or so. I've tried to recast it but that didn't help.

the code looks like this:

```
FILETIME* ctime = calloc(sizeof(FILETIME), 1);
SystemTimeToFileTime(time, ctime);

FILETIME* ttime = calloc(sizeof(FILETIME), 1);
SystemTimeToFileTime(anntime, ttime);

ULONGLONG qwResult;
ULONGLONG qwResult1;
// Copy the time into a quadword.
qwResult = (((ULONGLONG) ctime->dwHighDateTime) << 32) + ctime->dwLowDateTime;

qwResult1 = (((ULONGLONG) ttime->dwHighDateTime) << 32) + ttime->dwLowDateTime;

qwResult1 -= qwResult;

qwResult1 *= -1; // does not work
```

ctime is the current time and ttime is when the timer should signal. So i need a way to turn qwResult1 into a negative const LARGE_INTEGER that i can pass to SetWaitableTimer. and i have no idea how to do that conversion and would appreciate any help on the matter.

Comment: Presuming that `qwResult` is always smaller (earlier) than `qwResult1`, you could just reverse your operation: `qwResult -= qwResult1`, which should give you a negative value. (This is the equivalent of `4 - 8 == -4`.)

Comment: This seems like a good option, can i just stick the value back in a `FILETIME` and cast that to a `const LARGE_INTEGER` to pass to `SetWaitableTimer()` ?

Comment: I tried reversing the subtraction but it still gives me a value corresponding to 50000 years or so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, here are a few defines that can make dealing with `FILETIME` easier (remember `FILETIME` uses 100-nanosecond units):

```
#define FILETIMESEC     (10000000i64)
#define FILETIMEMIN     (FILETIMESEC * 60i64)
#define FILETIMEHOUR    (FILETIMEMIN * 60i64)
#define FILETIMEDAY     (FILETIMEHOUR * 24i64)
```

The [`SetWaitableTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686289%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function lets you set a timer for *either* an absolute or a relative time, so if you want a timer to go off in 30 seconds from now, you don't need to get the current time first - simply specify a relative time offset.

To specify a relative time, you need to provide a negative value. Therefore, you should use a `LARGE_INTEGER` structure - this is a union which includes a signed `LONGLONG` member.

```
LARGE_INTEGER li;
li.QuadPart = -(FILETIMESEC * 30);
SetWaitableTimer(hTimer, &li, 0, 0, 0, FALSE);
```

This will set the timer to go off in 30 seconds.

Comment: Yeah, i know how to set a timer off of a value provided by the user but i need to get the time between the current time and the time the timer should go off which might be a certain date. for example if it's 12:00 today and i want the timer to go off at 19:00 i need the timespan inbetween those two times

Comment: If you have an absolute time you want the timer to go off then you can just use that directly in `SetWaitableTimer` - you don't need to calculate the offset at all. Remember, positive values mean absolute time, negative values mean relative time.

Comment: I have a relative time, but i need to get the current time. And the time the user wants the timer to go off. Turn those into filetime since you can't do arithmetic on systemtime and get the difference in time, then use that in `SetWaitableTimer`

Comment: I understand what you mean now. I had to do some more research to figure it out. But i solved it by using absolute time. I converted the `ttime` with `LocalFileTimeToFileTime` then cast that to a `const LARGE_INTEGER*` and sent that to the timer which worked excellent. Thank you for the help.